# selenium with java @FindBy annotation cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium with java and the following pom package,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

I am able to use WebDriver and other object but when i try to use the annotation @FindBy it seems that my project cannot find a package that satisfy it "cannot be resolved as a type" as well it does not propose to use the selenium package.

In which maven repository is located the annotation system from selenium ?
Or am i missing something here ?

Thank you

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace

Comment: I think it's this:  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

Comment: Add a constructor to your pageclass like this:

    ```public YourClassName(){PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)};```

This should help if everything else is good.

Comment: Please add dependency for page factory in your pom.xml file.     
 ```<dependency>
 <groupId>ru.sbtqa.tag</groupId>
 <artifactId>page-factory</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.7</version>
</dependency>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download the client combine jar from selenium website which contains the package (import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;)