# Selenium version 3.141.59 @FindBy annotation giving error 'cannot be resolved as a type'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findby

I'm using the maven project with selenium 3.141.59 dependency.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

[Findby cannot be resolved to a type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap1kj.png)

while using @FindBy annotation, I am getting Findby cannot be resolved to a type error.
if I'm updating the selenium version to '4.0.0-rc-3' not getting any error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723020/selenium-with-java-findby-annotation-cannot-be-resolved-as-a-type

Comment: but I didn't get any solution for above one.

Comment: Try Maven -> Update -> Select force update -> ok and then clean your project

Comment: @NandanA tried it. still getting the same error for FindBy annotation

Comment: I believe you have this `import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;` already

Comment: @NandanA NO. just today I have imported a project to my new system. the same project setup is working fine in my old system.

Comment: Add that import and try

Comment: cloned the project from Github. but it's not working. tried with creating a new project manually as well. but getting the same issue.

Comment: Than might be issue with the your internet connection security is not allowing to download libraries from the maven repository. Try to connect with other network and use maven clean and update.